# Roboguice - Instantiating an object from a constructor with arguments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, roboguice

Recently I downloaded `Roboguice` and gave it a try. In general I like it and I think it could ease some aspects in Android development process, but I encountered a situation which didn't find a solution yet: I want to inject a class, but that class has one, ore more constructors with several parameters.

In a such case, how would I specify which constructor to choose for instantiation, and pass the values to constructor?

For example I have the the class `TestRobo` with 2 constructors, and I want to instantiate the object from the second constructor, passing the `firstName`, `lastName` as parameters:

```
public class TestRobo implements ITestRobo {

    public TestRobo(String fullName) {
        //....
    }

    public TestRobo(String firstName, String lastName) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Right now, if I inject it like this:

```
@Inject
private ITestRobo testRobo;
```

It trows an exception that it couldn't find a suitable constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind ITestRobo to its TestRobo implementation.  You can either do this by adding the @ProvidedBy(TestRobo.class) annotation to ITestRobo, or you can add a module and bind(ITestRobo.class).to(TestRobo.class) in your configure() method.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer 1: I am a newbie as well.

Disclaimer 2: Haven't tried this yet.

According to Google's own Guice Documentation, the way to specify which constructor to use is to add the @Inject decorator to it

```
    class Test{

    //This constructor is ignored
    Test(){}

    //This constructor is called during injection
    @Inject
    Test(Context pContext){}


    }
```

In this case the injector calls the second constructor and tries to inject a Context object to call it. If it can't be found then it will throw an exception.

Apparently, you can also put the @Inject decorator to other methods, which will be called after the constructor is called during an injection.

Source:[Official Google Guice Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectionPoints)